# Importxml - could not fetch url

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to get data from this website http://www.npo.gov.za/PublicNpo/Npo into Google Sheets

I am using the importxml function:
`=IMPORTXML("www.npo.gov.za/PublicNpo/Npo", "//table//tbody//tr//td[1]|//table//tbody//tr//td[20]")`

I get the error: could not fetch url www.npo.gov.za/PublicNpo/Npo

Comment: Did my answer work?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `http://` to the URL as follows?

#### From :

```
=IMPORTXML("www.npo.gov.za/PublicNpo/Npo", "//table//tbody//tr//td[1]|//table//tbody//tr//td[20]")
```

#### To :

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.npo.gov.za/PublicNpo/Npo", "//table//tbody//tr//td[1]|//table//tbody//tr//td[20]")
```